# Uable to understand function with @ symbol in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was just checking out the React Darg and drop examples on [HERE](http://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/examples-dustbin-single-target.html), and so when i checked the source , i see the following lines of code:

```
@DropTarget(ItemTypes.BOX, boxTarget, (connect, monitor) => ({
    connectDropTarget: connect.dropTarget(),
    isOver: monitor.isOver(),
    canDrop: monitor.canDrop(),
}))
```

I don't quite understand what these lines of code are doing or what exactly then mean, the entire component code can be found [HERE](https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/blob/master/packages/documentation/examples/01%20Dustbin/Single%20Target/Dustbin.js#L25) (its about 54 lines of JS.). Can somebody please example what these lines of code are doing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That `@DropTarget` is a [decorator function](https://medium.com/google-developers/exploring-es7-decorators-76ecb65fb841).

If you look at the [tutorial's section on dropTarget](http://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs-drop-target.html), you will see a button which let's you switch between ES7, ES6 and ES5 sample code.

As an alternative to using the decorator, you can simply call the decorator method with it's three parameters, and this will return a function which you can pass your component to. Here is the ES6 equivalent:

```
class Dustbin extends Component {
  ...
}

DropTarget(ItemTypes.BOX, boxTarget, (connect, monitor) => ({
  connectDropTarget: connect.dropTarget(),
  isOver: monitor.isOver(),
  canDrop: monitor.canDrop(),
}))(Dustbin)
```

You can have a look at the [source code of the DropTarget](https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/blob/master/packages/react-dnd/src/DropTarget.js) decorator to see how it works.

It does some pre-processing based on the arguments passed to it, then returns a  function which uses [decorateHandler](https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/blob/c6bf3afa54786f856f4fc89241a66479b0f9d1e4/packages/react-dnd/src/decorateHandler.js) to wrap your component in a custom component which handles the drop event.

Comment: Thanks for your well structured answer ! :)

Answer (score 3):

Those are [JavaScript Decorators](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-decorators/).

[They are](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators#decorators) currently [a stage-2 (Draft) proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposals#stage-2) (in a [4-stage process](https://tc39.github.io/process-document/)). This means they aren't part of JavaScript yet, but may become in the future.

Regardless of that, some transpilers, such as [**Babel**](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-decorators/) and [**TypeScript**](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html), already support them, so you could use them today, if you wanted.

And that's what's happening with that lib you linked (they used decorators in their code, but transpiled it before so they could execute in current version JavaScript).